# Nav <ul> is mouseout? How to fix

Tags: javascript, html, css, nav

I am not the best at wording my questions, sorry.
I am trying to make a sidenav which displays when you hover over a small strip on the side of the screen, then disappears on mouse out.

```
<!--the small bar on the side-->
<div id="sidebar"></div>

<!--the nav to display-->
<nav id="sidenav">
<ul>
<li>HOME</li>
<li>ABOUT</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Then I used some css to put them on the side and make them look pretty. Next, I added some JS:

```
<div id="sidebar" onmouseenter="show()">""</div>
<nav id="sidenav" onmouseout="hide()">""</nav>

<script>
function show() {
    document.getElementById("sidebar").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("sidenav").style.display = "block";
}

function hide() {
    document.getElementById("sidebar").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("sidenav").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

The scirpt works fine, just as I want it to. The only problem I am running into is that when I try to hover over the list items, the hide() function runs, as if it takes me entering the UL as a mouseout.

P.S. I am currently in the process of learning JS so please bare that in mind when making judgment calls.

Comment: This is probably something better handled with CSS. CSS has `:hover` and the `+` sibling selector.

Comment: Yup, CSS is capable of a lot of things: http://tympanus.net/Development/SidebarTransitions/

Comment: That's really odd, since you're not calling `hide()` anywhere in your posted code.

Comment: Really hard to know what you are trying to accomplish here.  Maybe put up a working example by using the code snippet.

Comment: Oh, thank you lol that was a typo. But I got answers so I'm sure it was understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simplistic solution with CSS:

```css
#sidebar {
  background: blue;
}
#sidenav {
  background: red;
  display: none;
}
#parent:hover #sidebar {
  display: none;
}
#parent:hover #sidenav {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="sidebar">""</div>
  <nav id="sidenav">""</nav>
</div>
```

There a lot of things that can be improved on from this way, but it's a good start.

Comment: Thank you. I considered doing this from the start, but wasn't sure how to go about it and/or if there was a better way to do it. Seeing it actually put to action though, it's really simple and easy to work with.